# Kubernetes - Can I Pass PodID to my Docker Container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We deploy our dockerized java applications to our various environments via kubernetes. We have a need to provide the podID to each docker container inside the pod.

Update: so I should have been more clear. I know already from this handy link from an old posting [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) , that I can retrieve the podID value during configuration of deploying container this way:

```
  env:
    - name: MY_POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
```

My question is how can I either pass this id to the docker container, OR, just as good, is there a way the container can retrieve this information from it's kubernetes context/environment?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: what you mean by  pod id?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu, i mean status.podIP

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu, for instance, I know from the yaml file I can things like:      ` env:
         - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP`

Comment: It seems like the downward API fragment you quoted is what you're looking for...what do you need other than that?

Comment: @DavidMaze, what I perhaps should have asked was how can the docker container get that piece of information. I don't care whether I somehow  "forward" (whatever that would even mean) to the docker container, or else the docker container can somehow read from and retrieve the information from the kubernetes context it is running in. Does that help?

Comment: That fragment sets an environment variable `$MY_POD_IP` that the container has access to.  You don't need to "forward" it or have access back to the Kubernetes API or anything else.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze. that answered my question. I did not realize that the container by default has access to the environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you do this by using the Downward API, let me try and explain:

When defining this stanza in your pod yaml:

```
- name: MY_POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

**You get the pod IP via an environment variable name `MY_POD_IP` inside your container**

Comment: thanks so that was my misunderstanding. I did not realize that the environment variable I define is automatically available to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the podIP through environment.

```
- name: MY_POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

For Details clieck [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables)